# Hebrew Grammar: How did Nif'al end up as the passive/reflexive of pa'al?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

I have been trying to figure this out by comparing Hebrew binyanim to Arabic and Akkadian conjuations. But I cannot figure it out.

Is Nif'al a natural part of the G-stem (like pa'al) or has it "wandered" there over the millenia when the original passive and reflexive G-stem conjugations died out? Where did it come from?

Nif'al just doesn't seem very equivalent to Hitpa'el even though as a reflexive of pa'al it should be.

Comment: An interesting (if unpopular) hypothesis is advanced in this paper regarding passive-counterpart-בנין drift and what the proto-system should have looked like. http://www.jstor.org/pss/1515901 I would summarize it as an answer but I haven't read it since back when I studied "Bible" and read German.

Comment: Bah. They want US$34 for a four-page article...

Comment: Sorry about that. You could try your local univesity library. . . or email me separately.

Comment: Can't find a way to email you.

Comment: Bummer. I think this is off topic.